# Can I connect an inverter directly after an MPPT controller, with no battery?

Tags: energy, electricity, photovoltaics

Is it possible to connect a 12VDC to 220VAC inverter to the output of an MPPT solar charge controller, with no battery? This will be cheaper than having a full solar inverter, which can be really expensive.

Update: I don't need batteries, because it's a pump that's used to water a garden, and is only need when there is enough sun for the solar panels.

Possible secondary question: Would I need a VFD to control the motor of the pump?

Comment: Would you have batteries anywhere in the system? What type of loads are you trying to power?

Comment: If you don't get the answer you need here you could try posting to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello LShaver! I don't need any batteries in my system, I'm trying to power a water pump at the end.

Comment: @Zizo - OK, can you add this info to the question? Also, does the pump need to run continuously, or on demand, or x hours/day, or...?

Comment: I think the question on the VFD definitely belongs over at electronics.SE. Off the cuff, I'd say probably not, assuming it's a smallish pump.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the answer to your question is yes: there are many examples of irrigation systems employing a pump powered directly by solar power, with no battery energy storage. A quick search indicates there are numerous suppliers and types/scales of systems, and even a few youtube videos with DIY-guides to setting such a system up.

Specifically, it would depend on the components you have or intend to purchase: what are the specifications of your solar panels, charge controller, inverter, and pump, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is very much possible. 
While purchasing the Inverter , look for  " BATTERY-LESS ", and you will have your desired product.
Just a suggestion, a Taiwan based company has such model of Inverter with in-built MPPT controller. Google for  INVEREX INFINI

Comment: Are you associated with that company in any way - you're required to declare if so.

Comment: No.  I have No connection, no association with that company.  I have used this product.  So I gave advice based on my personal experience.